# Relative positioning to an absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css

I am experimenting with single-page design, and have built a page out of a number of different pages, by essentially creating a column of `<div>` elements each at 100% of the window height, and positioned absolutely one under another.

Each page, therefore, requires it's elements to be set absolutely, since there is (as far as I can tell) no normal document flow to follow. However, when it comes to text, I am finding it difficult to design. I'd like to try and keep the current design, rather than start over.

On a particular page, I have a text container. In that container, there are two titles. The first title heads two small paragraphs, the second heads one:

**HTML**

```
<div id="introTextContainer">
    <div id="introTextHeader" class="blurbheader">First title</div>
    <div id="introText" class="blurb">
            Generic text about the roots of the company
    </div>
    <div id="introTextParg2" class="blurb">
            further information about the roots
    </div>
    <div id="introStatement1" class="blurb StrongStatement">
            Second title
    </div>
    <div id="introTextParg3" class="blurb">
            Eye-catching mission statement
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blurb {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-right:10px;
    font-size: 1.4vh
}

.blurbheader {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 2vh;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.StrongStatement {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#introTextContainer {
    height: 20%;
    width: 45%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 10%;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

#introTextHeader {
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    left: 30px;    
    top: 5px;
    height: 10%;
}

#introText {
    position:absolute;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: Lato;
}

#introTextParg2 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 10px;
}

#introStatement1 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 30px;
}

#introTextParg3 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 10px;
}
```

At a standard resolution of 1080p, all of this looks perfectly acceptable. However, when the resolution is changed, the design is not responsive to the same. As you can see with the CSS, I have been experimenting with viewport-height for the text, however the spacing and height of the `<div>` elements is a different matter.

How can I create a positioning/size context within the scope of the text containers, in order that I can set the height and padding of the text paragraphs therein, within the scope of those containers? The current approach uses javascript, but I don't like the idea of attempting to use javascript to target every screen size possible as this would result in a lot of spaghetti code. Ideally, I would like to use javascript only to set the heights of the "page" `<div>` elements and the containing boxes.

**edit: CSS, JS, HTML of page design**

The first page is given a width and height of 100%. The subsequent pages are altered with JQuery. The value `data-section-name` is used in the seamless scrolling plugin. The canvas is used only to house the background image:

**HTML**

```
<section id="pageOne" class="panel pageone" data-section-name="sectionpageOne"> <!-- About -->
    <canvas id="pageOneCanvas"></canvas>

        <div id="introTextContainer">
        <div id="introTextHeader" class="blurbheader">First title</div>
        <div id="introText" class="blurb">
            Generic text about the roots of the company
        </div>
        <div id="introTextParg2" class="blurb">
            further information about the roots
        </div>
        <div id="introStatement1" class="blurb StrongStatement">
            Second title
        </div>
        <div id="introTextParg3" class="blurb">
            Eye-catching mission statement
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#pageOne {
    position: absolute;
    /*top: 0;*/
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#pageOneCanvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url("/Resources/images/aboutcanvas.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.6
}
```

**JS**

```
// Canvas height and positioning
var posheight = $(window).height();

$("#home").height(posheight);
$("#pageOne").height(posheight);
$("#pageTwo").height(posheight);
$("#pageThree").height(posheight);
$("#pageFour").height(posheight);
$("#pageFive").height(posheight);

$("#pageOne").css("top", posheight);
$("#pageTwo").css("top", (posheight * 2));
$("#pageThree").css("top", (posheight * 3));
$("#pageFour").css("top", (posheight * 4));
$("#pageFive").css("top", (posheight * 5));
```

Additionally, the current solution for fixing the text container dimensions is also in JS. You can start to see why I want to achieve this in CSS, as it's becoming messy here:

```
var introTextTitleHeight = $("#introTextHeader").height();


$("#introText").css("top", (introTextTitleHeight + 10));
$("#introTextParg2").css("top", ($("#introText").position().top + $("#introText").height() + 10));
$("#introStatement1").css("top", ($("#introTextParg2").position().top + $("#introTextParg2").height() + 10));
$("#introTextParg3").css("top", ($("#introStatement1").position().top + $("#introStatement1").height() + 10));
```

Comment: could you include the css and html of the surrounding page?

Comment: I don't understand why the divs in #introTextConainer need to be absolute.

Comment: Why don't you use *visibility* to implement the single-page aspect? You can have `div.page { display: none; }`, as well as `div.page.active { display: block; }`, then give and take `active` class to .page divs to *navigate* between them.

Comment: so you want different css for the components contained in the different containers?

Comment: @ThijsSteel I have added some additional information. I'm not sure what you mean by your second comment.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour I have used visibility in another project, as well as opacity to provide a nice transition. However, here I want to be able to continually scroll down with each "page" appearing after the other. Using visibility is a little jarring, and I have already worked hard on getting the scroll to work properly.

Comment: "How can I create a positioning/size context within the scope of the text containers, in order that I can set the height and padding of the text paragraphs therein, within the scope of those containers?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would removing `position: absolute;` on the child divs not do what you want?
And use `margin-left` instead of `left`.

So the rules would look like this:

```
#introTextHeader {
    margin-left: 30px;    
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 10%;
}

#introText {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: Lato;
}

#introTextParg2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#introStatement1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#introTextParg3 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that by using `position: absolute` on the containing div, I establish a separate document flow within that containing div, and can then treat it as if it were a top-level parent element?

Comment: Yes, the child elements will be relative to the parent, even if it's absolute.